# How to update a watchOS Smart Stack widget from the iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, watchos, widgetkit

Can the Smart Stack widget be updated on watchOS from the iOS counterpart app?

Let's say I have a widget that displays a counter, and you can increment this counter from the watch app or from the iOS app.

Updating the counter from the watch OS app is quite straightforward.

If the watchOS app is in the foreground and the counter is incremented on the iOS app I can use `WCSession` to transmit data and update it accordingly.

But what if the watchOS app is in the background or closed? Is there any way to update it? Anything remotely similar to [reloadTimelineForComplication](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/clockkit/clkcomplicationserver/1627891-reloadtimelineforcomplication)?